# This is a infinite loop but the first if is not working when it come to the second time

Tags: python, loops

```
while counter == 1:
    NUsername = input()+"\n"
    Username_list_in_SignUp = Username_list.readlines()
    if NUsername in Username_list_in_SignUp:
        print("Y")
    if NUsername not in Username_list_in_SignUp:
        print("N")
```

1. Initially there is a Username call "Justin" in the Username_list but when I run it the first time it will check whether the username is duplicated or not but the second time I key in Justin it does not check and print a "N" for me. How should I solve this problem.

ps: first time here at stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve]. In your example, the code you have provided is not reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readlines` moves the file pointer to the end of the file. You should do that only once, before the loop. There is no need to read the file again and again anyway:

```
Username_list_in_SignUp = Username_list.readlines()  # here!
# or for better contains check performance 
# Username_list_in_SignUp = set(Username_list.readlines())  
while counter == 1:
    NUsername = input()+"\n"
    if NUsername in Username_list_in_SignUp:
        print("Y")
    else:  # suffices
    # elif NUsername not in Username_list_in_SignUp:
        print("N")
```

Any further call to `readlines` of the same file handle will result in an empty list, unless you move the pointer back, e.g. via `Username_list.seek(0)`.